# How to get all headers in a XWPFDocument

Tags: maven, apache-poi, docx

I'm trying to extract all the headers in a docx file that I have.
This is the code I use:

```
 FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(new File("myfile.docx"));
 XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fs));
 List<XWPFHeader> list = doc.getHeaderList();
```

And if I do:

```
System.out.println(list.size());
```

It prints out 0, but I have 4 headers in my document.
The only way I have succeeded to extract any text from my document is by using the following code:

```
 XWPFWordExtractor wx = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);  
 String text = wx.getText();  
 System.out.println("text = "+text );
```

This is the structure of my document:

[image]

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Comment: I am not really familiar with the .docx part of POI but looking at the API it would seems getHeaderList() may return the PAGE headers. Insert some page headers and footers and then see what getHeaderList() and getFooterList() return. The headers you are referring to are just styles.

Comment: Do you want `Page Headers` or `Headings`?